# Powerpivot and Slicers

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I've got a very simple powerpivot table with some slicers in it. When someone drills the table down to one user with the slicer, I managed to create another measure which returns the average for the whole team. This works just fine.

The problem is that the grand total average stays the same regardless of which user has been selected.

**1.**

[image]

**2.**

[image]

**3.**

[image]

Screen 1 and 2 shows you that depending on the user, I see the users AHT and teams AHT. That works out well.

The problem is that even though on those two screens I have different types in the row labels, the grand total is still the same - the grand total averages everything regardless of what user/type is selected.

Any ideas? thanks up front!

Answer (score 0):

Your [Team AHT] ignores all filter context placed on 'AHT'[User]. All other filter context is maintained. The simplest would be to add a slicer or filter on something other than 'AHT'[User] to modify the measure evaluation in your report.